# Are there any risks/issues using a List's hashCode as key for caching results?

Tags: apex, cache

I'm considering using a combination of `static` variables and the `List` object's `hashCode` method to cache the results of a SOQL call based on the values being passed in (`accountIds`). The methods will be service methods (not always called from Lightning Components).

Here's a simple example:

```
private static Map<Integer, List<Account>> accountCache;
public static List<Account> GetAccounts(List<Id> accountIds) {
    if(accountCache.get(accountIds.getHashcode()) == null) {
        accountCache.put(accountIds.getHashcode(), [select Id from Accounts limit 10]);
    }
    return accountCache.values();
}
```

A few questions:

1. Can I count on the List's `hashCode` to be a reliable key for this caching scenario?
2. Are there any other issues that might cause this code to not work as I expect it to?
3. Are there any best practices (or platform services) I'm overlooking to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, hashCode is reliable, although strictly speaking, unnecessary. You could use the object itself:

```
private static Map<Object, List<Account>> accountCache;
public static List<Account> GetAccounts(List<Id> accountIds) {
    if(accountCache.get(accountIds) == null) {
        accountCache.put(accountIds, [select Id from Accounts limit 10]);
    }
    return accountCache.get(accountIds);
}
```

---

> Can I count on the List's hashCode to be a reliable key for this caching scenario?

Yes, it's perfectly reliable.

> Are there any other issues that might cause this code to not work as I expect it to?

Your caching algorithm doesn't account for partial matches. For example, if you query accounts 1,2,3,4, then later, accounts 1,2,3,4,5, you've queried four extra accounts a second time, and you have two copies of them in memory.

In addition, there's a very, very small (but non-zero) chance that the hash will collide with a different set of values. Using the object version, above, as the key, prevents this collision possibility.

> Are there any best practices (or platform services) I'm overlooking to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

What I can say is that a more comprehensive strategy should be used. Something like this:

```
static Map<Id, Account> accountCache = new Map<Id, Account>();
public static Account[] getAccounts(Id[] accountIds) {
  Set<Id> newAccounts = new Set<Id>(accountIds);
  newAccounts.removeAll(accountCache.keySet());
  if(!newAccounts.isEmpty()) {
    accountCache.putAll([SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = :newAccounts]);
  }
  Map<Id, Account> results = new Map<Id, Account>(accountCache.values());
  results.keySet().retainAll(accountIds);
  return results.values();
}
```

Comment: I would actually say it is far, far better (not just preferable) to use the array itself because it then uses both the hash code and content equality which helps avoid hash code collisions.

Comment: @PhilW Good point. Mind you, collisions are already exceptionally rare, but birthday paradox is a thing. I'll edit that in.

Comment: @sfdcfox on line 8 (`Map<Id, Account> results = new Map<Id, Account>(accountCache.values());`) couldn't you have just done this: `Map<Id, Account> results = accountCache.clone();`?

Comment: @SwisherSweet Yes. Not entirely sure why I wrote it the way I did, it's roughly equivalent in terms of performance, but using clone would read better here, since that's what we're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Apex "borrows" from Java, [hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) has an "As much as is reasonably practical" contract which when you go to the trouble of building a cache, is not a solid base. So as a matter of style, best avoided.

Comment: Indeed. Much what I was meaning with the concern about collisions in my comment on fox's answer.